# Concatenación de query

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente query y estoy actualizando datos de dos bases de datos, la situación esta en que el campo Fecha_Nacimiento de la bd vieja tiene la fecha de nacimiento total dd/mm/aaa y en cambio la nueva esta separada fechaNacimiento1Padre para dd, fechaNacimiento2Padre para mm,fechaNacimiento3Padre para aaaa.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer la concatenación? :

```
select sc_familia.codigo as 'familia',
                                    padre.Fecha_Nacimiento as 'fechaNacimiento1Padre',
                                    padre.exalumno as 'exAlumnoPadre',
                                    alumno.direccion as 'direccionAlumno',
                                    alumno.telefono as 'telefonoAlumno',
                                    alumno.correo_electronico as 'emailAlumno',
                                    alumno.Fecha_nacimiento as 'nacimientoAlumno',
                                    concat(padre.apellidos, ', ', padre.nombres) as 'nombrePadre',
                                    concat(madre.apellidos, ', ', madre.nombres) as 'nombreMadre',
                                                                           encargado.idsc_persona as 'idEncargado'
                             from sc_familia
                                  left join sc_persona as padre
                                       on padre.idsc_persona =  sc_familia.idsc_persona_padre
                                  left join sc_persona as madre
                                       on madre.idsc_persona =  sc_familia.idsc_persona_madre
                                  left join sc_persona as encargado
                                      on encargado.idsc_persona = sc_familia.idsc_persona_encargado
                                  left join sc_alumno as alumno
                                      on alumno.idsc_familia = sc_familia.idsc_familia`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select year(padre.Fecha_Nacimiento) año,
       month(padre.Fecha_Nacimiento) mes,
       day(padre.Fecha_Nacimiento) dia
```